# SQL lazy update operations

Tags: sql, sql-server, multithreading, lazy-evaluation

We insert SQL entities into a table, one by one. It's easy and fast. After the entity insert, we are executing an SP to updates several tables according to the new entity, update some calculated fields, some lookup tables to help to find this new entity. This takes a lot of time and sometimes ends up in a deadlock state.

Inserting the main entity must be fast and reliable, updating the additional tables is not important to happen immediately. I was wondering (I am not a DB expert) if there is an SQL methodology similar to the thread handling in C#, to maintain an update thread, which can be awakened when a new entity arrives to update the additional tables after the insertion. This thread can update these tables in "one thread" to avoid deadlock.

I can imagine an sql job which executes every minute, searches for new entities and executes the updates, but it seems too rough to me.

What is the best practice to implement this on MS SQL side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could achieve this. You mention that the two can be done separately - immediate updating is not important. In that case, you could set up a SQL Agent to run a stored procedure that checks for missing records and performs the update.

Another approach would be to put the entire original update inside a stored procedure responsible for performing the update and all the housekeeping work, then all you would do is call the stored procedure with the right parameters and it would do all the work behind the curtain.

Another way would be to add triggers on the inserted table to do the update for you. Sounds like the first is what you probably want.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Agents, but to make clear - the backend inserts a new entity, and that's all. The additional steps can be done later. If I put all steps into an SP - the backend must wait for the finish. But the backend is not interested in the additional steps. The trigger method is the same. The backend do not want to wait for the finish - the success of the insert operation. What I want is to notify a background "thread" that there are new entities waiting to be finished - and don't want to wait to be finished.

Comment: The agent can be executed at a scheduled time. It is not so good. To be executed in every minute - when no entitiy arrived in the last 3 hours. :( But when 10 new entity in a second - launch it 10 times won't work. How to configure the agent to execute in a very short time after the insert operation, but do not execute when no entity inserted?

Comment: Create a queue Record the records in the queue and then the agent can run on those. If there is nothing in the queue then the agent will finish in microseconds.

Comment: Ahhh that's ok. Then what? When the Agent finishes - how will it start again? When or why? Remain running, or start again? Starting an Agent is a big overhad.

Comment: You just set it to run every however often you want. It's really not that big a deal, unless you are trying to do some stupidly large query every few seconds.